# slicing template and designing layout, central body inside wrapper

Tags: css, layout, xhtml, html

I have a pdf template with layout like in below sample pdf image:

[image]

**Description of PDF**
Overall size of template is width 1600 x height 1335 px (in example image shown as green background) On top it will have a news / text scrolling which will be covering full width of page but its body part will be less (it is the area in white, gray, and black colors).

**What I want?**
This layout may be fit on minimum 1024 x 786 px and maixumum on any width.

How should I develop page layout?

Fixed outer green box width and inner box width? both in percentage? or any one fixed and other in percentage?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of what you want is a body element with a 100%  width and a container that has a width of 1024 px. Setting margin-left and margin-right to auto will center them in the parent body.  This would fit your basic requirements.

```
body
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#container
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1024px;
    min-height: 768px;
    text-align: left;
}
```